# Manually update layer params in Flux

Tags: julia, flux.jl

How do I manually set the weights of a layer in Flux? The layer are immutable structs so they can't be updated directly:

```
> a = rand(Float64, (2, 3))
> d = Dense(3, 2, relu)
> d.W = a
ERROR: setfield! immutable struct of type Dense cannot be changed
```

The `update!` function assumes the use of a gradient. While I could probably hack a gradient matrix together to use `update!(x, x̄)`, that doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Ideally, I'd like to write some function that takes the existing weights, calculates new weights, and then sets those new weights, like `d.W = func(d.W; args)`

Comment: If it's a simple feed-forward neural network on the CPU you can do it easily with `getParam` and `setParam` in the [BetaML toolkit](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/dev/Nn.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When d.W is a normal Matrix, use `d.W .= a`.

However, when d.W is a Tracked Matrix, you need to do `d.W.data .= a`

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, the `Dense` structure is defined as **immutable**. However, you can still modify the parameters with `d.W .= a`.